# What is the grammatical function of "become indispensable summer and winter" here?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

From *Walden* by Thoreau:

> The rest pay an annual tax for this outside garment of all, *become indispensable summer and winter*, which would buy a village of Indian wigwams, but now helps to keep them poor as long as they live.

I think it modifies the *outside garment of all* (house), but it looks awkward as a relative construction here.

Comment: Thus antiquated/stylised text is over 150 years old, and many native speakers would struggle with it today. The metaphoric *outside garment **of all*** (meaning "house") would be more easily understood as ***outermost** garment*. The following clause would be easier to understand if we paraphrased it to *...this outermost garment, **which has** become indispensable **all year round***. Unfortunately Thoreau couldn't do that in his exact context, because of the *next* supplementary clause *[an annual tax] **which would buy** a village of Indian wigwams*. Two "nested" ***which**'s* don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a relative construction (though some linguists would call it a 'relative clause reduced by Whiz-deletion') but the past participle employed as an adjectival. It is placed after the noun it modifies because it is followed by its complement, and it is bracketed off with commas because it is supplemental and non-restrictive—an additional predication.

It feels odd to you because today we rarely use this construction with intransitive verbs: the participle is ordinarily taken to bear a passive sense, and intransitive verbs of course cannot be passivized. The construction was more common when the perfects of *become* and verbs of motion were formed with *be* rather than *have*; Thoreau 'hears' the full predication as

> This outside garment **is** become indispensable.